# php not returning variable for display

Tags: php

I have a html/php that queries a database and downloads the results to a csv file.  That part works fine.  But, I want to display the text of the variable $message in the text box of the html page.  If I do not do the fputcsv section, it works.  But I cannot get it to display if the file gets downloaded.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php 

include('members.db.inc.php');

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if(isset($_POST['Info_Verify'])){
$message1="Export Information Verification.";
ExportFile ("Information_Verification");
$message = $message1;
}

if(isset($_POST['Members'])){
$message="Export Member Import List.";
ExportFile ("Member_Import_List");
}
if(isset($_POST['GMail'])){
$message="Export Gmail Import List.";
ExportFile ("GMail_Import_List");
}


function ExportFile($temp) {

//echo $temp;
$error = 0;
$filename = $temp . ".csv";
$sql = sprintf("Select * from " . $temp);
//print $sql . '<br>';

$result = DBi::$conn->query($sql);
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records'. DBi::$conn->connect_error) . '<br>';

$headers = $result->fetch_fields();

foreach($headers as $header) {
    $head[] = $header->name;
}

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($head)); 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
        }
    fclose($fp);
    exit;
    }
}    


?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Export Information</title>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
border: 1px solid #000000;
text-align: center;
}
.auto-style2 {
border: 3px solid #000000;
}
.auto-style3 {
border: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Export_Form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"     method=post>
<input type="text" name="txt" value="<?php if(isset($message)){ echo $message;}?>" style="width: 688px" ><br>
<br>&nbsp;<br>
<table style="width: 100%" class="auto-style2">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 208px">
<input type="submit" name="Info_Verify" value="Information Verification"></td>
        <td class="auto-style3">
        House_Number,Street_Name,Member_Name,Phone_Number_1,Phone_Number_2,Zip_Code,Email1,EMail2,Communication_Code,Hide_Information</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 208px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 208px">
<input type="submit" name="Members" value="Members" ></td>
        <td class="auto-style3">"Home Address",Name,"Home Phone","Home Phone 
        2","E-Mail Address","E-Mail 2 Address",Categories"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 208px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1" style="width: 208px">
<input type="submit" name="GMail" value="GMail Export" ></td>
        <td class="auto-style3">Name,"E-mail Address","E-mail 2 
        Address",Categories</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>&nbsp;
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can either output a csv file, or html, not both.

Comment: I thought that may be the case.  Can I not change the header back after the file is written so that if will output to html after the file is saved?

Comment: Unfortunately not, an http response can only have a single content type. You will need to use a two step process